# Navigation only in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have iframe in the site which acts as an internal browser. I know that frames are generally bad idea but I was not able to find alternative. The question is how to prevent navigation of browser when user clicks a link inside iframe - only iframe has to be redirected, not ALL browser. Sites inside iframe are limited, very simple - mostly static HTML, maybe I can use javascript to add target='iframe_name' to each link inside iframe's HTML if it's possible.. ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can change all the links with this simple code:

```
iFrameText = iFrameText.replace(/(<a\s)/ig, "$1target='iframe_name' ")
```

This, can however create problems if you are having "target" set for some of the links. I think the latter will take the preference.

Comment: That's not very stable, and not really necessary.

Comment: Thanks, though I made a mistake with assumption that I can access inner text of the iframe - it's forbidden since contents are fetched from other domain. I get permission denied error in Javascript. Are there any other workarounds to consider ?

Comment: You can put the code inside of the loaded pages (if that is possible) and check if you are running within the frame - then you can change the `target` attribute.

As for JavaScript access denied, I believe it was done to prevent hidden parent document with single `<iframe>` taking the whole screen. This way you would be able to spy pages visited by user.

Answer (score 3):

The normal operation of HTML `<a>` tags is alread to replace only the current frame.

Here is a simple, sample page: http://gutfullofbeer.net/frames/able.html

when you click on the links in the box, the frame reloads. Those are just simple `<a>` tags.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that thanks, but it seems that target is given explicitly so I may need to overwrite it somehow, however as I written in the comment above it's forbidden since iframe points to other domain.